# Vibrate function on my Samsung Galaxy S3 doesn't work though it is turned on. What is the cause?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, notifications, vibration

I have had this phone for a few months and only now did I try to start using the vibrate function.  When I choose "Vibrate" from the drop-down bar it never vibrates when I receive texts though sometimes it works when I use the Facebook messenger app.  I went into settings and enabled everything that has the word "Vibrate" in it.  Also, my phone is on power-saving mode; does that have any impact?

The vibrate function is supposed to notify you of incoming notifications but by vibrate, yes?

Is it a hardware problem?

OS: 4.1.1
Model: SGH-l747M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power saving mode (by default) turns off some vibration, but it should only turn off the "haptic feedback" vibration (vibration when you touch certain UI controls). You can change that by going to Settings, Power saving mode, and unchecking "Turn off haptic feedback". That's the mode I run my SGS3 in all the time.

To get vibration working for text messages, you also need to enable vibration in the settings of the `Messaging` app itself (I'm not sure which settings you were referring to when you said that you "went into settings and enabled everything that has the word "Vibrate" in it"). To do that, go to the conversation list in the Messaging app (not an individual conversation), hit the menu button, then select Settings. Look for the "Notification Settings" section and check "Vibrate".

To get vibration working for incoming calls, there is a similar setting in the `Phone` app. Launch the `Phone` app, make sure you're on the `Keypad`, `Logs`, or `Favorites` tab, tap the menu button, select `Call settings`. Then select `Ringtones and keypad tones` and select `Incoming call vibration`. The `Device vibration` will let you modify the vibration pattern used (so you can tell an incoming call from a text message / email).

To get to the `Phone` and `Messaging` apps: Press the "home" button at the bottom of the phone (the physical button in the middle). That brings you to your home screen. The touch the "Apps" button (it looks like 9 square white dots, and is usually on the lower right of the home screen). That will bring up a list of all applications installed on the phone. Scroll through looking for an app named `Messaging` (or `Phone`). The icon for the `Messaging` app looks like a white envelope with a yellow piece of paper coming out of it. The icon for the `Phone` app looks like a green square with a white phone receiver on it. Tap the app icon, then follow the instructions for each app above to activate vibration for text messaging and incoming calls.

Comment: My haptic mode has always been off.  I was using Facebook as an example to show that the vibrate function works sometimes but my actual concern is getting notified of incoming calls and texts when my phone is in vibrate-only mode.

Comment: I went into my phone "Settings" to make sure all options that have to do with the vibration mode was on.

Comment: It's good that you've enabled vibration in the "Settings" app. But it's not enough. You also have to enable it in both the `Messaging` app and the `Phone` app. See my answer for instructions, if you need them.

Comment: What exactly is the Messaging app?  I'm not interested in getting notifications from Facebook but the text messages I receive directly on my phone. I'm lost.

Comment: I can't find my Phone app. Where is it and what does it look like?

Comment: What about text messages?  How can I get that working?

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. I'm at work and had to wait until lunch time to respond. I've edited my answer again with instructions on how to get to the `Phone` (the app that handles making and receiving calls) and `Messaging` (the apps that handles sending and receiving text messages) apps.

Comment: Awesome , found the text one.  Under Ringtones in the phone app vibrate is already enabled.  Let me try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it in other modes than power saving. To make you phone in Vibrate only mode, hit the volume keys till the volume bars come down and shows the vibrate mode.

Yes when on vibrate mode all notification via WhatsApp or FB messenger will be via vibration only.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with the vibration for my phone even when vibration was turned on for calls/texts/etc  until I realized  it was because the vibration intensity was turned all the way down.  Go  to Settings,  click on Sound,  then  click on  Vibration Intensity  and make sure it's turned up.